# Change MySQL comparison value when query returns 0 records

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I'm having trouble selecting records when there are not records returned.
What I'm trying to do is select records based on language. In this case the language has "language_id" number 3. So the problem is this query returns 0 records. If that's the case I want to change language_id to 1 witch is in this case the default language.

If tried to do it with exists but then I can't create a new selection. Can anybody help me out a bit, is it even possible to change the query value that is in the comparison part ?

```
SELECT `sepc`.`value` FROM (`items_2_extra_properties_columns` AS sepc)
WHERE `sepc`.`item_id` = '58489' 
AND `sepc`.`property_id` = '10799' 
AND `sepc`.`lang_id` = '3')
```

Comment: can't do it with a single query - `where` applies on a per-row basis, and any "meta values", like total number of rows found, won't be known until all rows have been processed. could try using `having`, which applies once all meta values are known (e.g. basically the last step before sending results to the client), but having also can't go back in time and pull data from some other location if the first filter doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the same query in a sub-query to get count and switch language id based on the count as follows:

```
SELECT `sepc`.`value` FROM (`items_2_extra_properties_columns` AS sepc)
WHERE `sepc`.`item_id` = '58489' 
AND `sepc`.`property_id` = '10799' 
AND CASE WHEN 
(SELECT COUNT(`sepc`.`value`) FROM  (`items_2_extra_properties_columns` AS sepc) WHERE `sepc`.`item_id` = '58489' AND `sepc`.`property_id` = '10799' AND `sepc`.`lang_id` = '3')=0
THEN `sepc`.`lang_id` = '1' ELSE `sepc`.`lang_id` = '3'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

use if statement and if first result null it will execute the second

```
SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT `sepc`.`value` FROM (`items_2_extra_properties_columns` AS sepc)
WHERE `sepc`.`item_id` = '58489' 
AND `sepc`.`property_id` = '10799' 
AND `sepc`.`lang_id` = '3'),
(SELECT `sepc`.`value` FROM (`items_2_extra_properties_columns` AS sepc)
WHERE `sepc`.`item_id` = '58489' 
AND `sepc`.`property_id` = '10799' 
AND `sepc`.`lang_id` = '1')) AS value;
```

Comment: Ok almost the records return more value's then one. 
It now gives me a error "more then one rows are returned" because there are more records. 
How can I retrieve all the records and not just one ?